# Customizing Android

Tags: android, embedded, linux-kernel

I want to use Android for a system I have in order to use it as an embedded system that would run a specific application (which runs in chrome browser). However, this will not use Android in ordinary way, but rather hack around it so that libraries like OpenCV and packages like Chromium can be installed on the Android's Linux kernel. In addition, I would also need to figure out a way that would allow a USB camera to be supported.

I have done some research on this, but I am getting nowhere. Would somebody recommend resources that are relevant to this issue, or suggestions on how to approach it? Your feedback would be much appreciated.

Edit1: I am not intending for this question to be too broad. I only want to get more ideas on how you add libraries like OpenCV to Android, and whether there is a way to install the chrome browser as well.

Edit2: the Android system is on the Snapdragon platform.

Comment: I do not think it is broad. I am looking for something that will get me started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Chromium and OpenCV can be built on Linux, have you tried compiling them from source on Android and failed? What error did you get? Here's a link for cross-compiling Chrome for ARM processors:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxChromiumArm

I would use http://www.android-x86.org/ first and see if it works there before trying to run it on ARM so that you can fail faster if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to spend some time with ROM hackers to get more insight.  Ideally, you want to find some people who are doing something similar so you can work with them.  Take a look at:

http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/

http://forum.xda-developers.com/

A lot of what those guys are doing does not apply to what you are looking for, but they do get much deeper into the OS than most programmers.   You might get lucky, and not have to modify the Android source code yourself as thinksteep mentions.